# Android SQLite:How to search a specific value in a database?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I am creating a database based application which requires to search through the database in a specific column for a name and then list all entries which are filtered by the keyword.
For example
Database entries:

```
1   Test    123 chicken
```

If someone searches chicken, it will output or direct towards the entry 1.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `WHERE` clause along with your `SELECT` statement,

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE name = 'chicken'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String arg = "chicken";
String query = "select * from table_name where title=\""+ arg + "\"";
Cursor cs = mSqlDB.rawQuery(query, null);
```

You should have your selected row in cursor cs.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you have a button and you click it...Try it:

```
Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_button);

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                String searchStr = search.getText().toString();  // Here is "chicken"

                Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT Id, Name, Price FROM "+SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME+" WHERE Name like '"+searchStr+"'", null);

                if (c != null ) { 
                    if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {

                            int idNumber = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Id"));

                            Log.v("IdNumber", id);

                        }while (c.moveToNext());
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: I understan your method the best however, I have two classes. DbMain extends Main. DbMain handles the Database. Main handles all the Button and EditText functions. From what I see in your example, your using the database cursor functions in the same class with the buttons. Due to how I made this work. It doesn't seem to work. I may be doing something wrong. Is it possible that I can make that function return the value instead?